# Declare natural transform for batching with kind-projector

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, higher-kinded-types, kind-projector

I have the following trait:

```
trait Test[F[_]]{
  def foo: F[Int]
}
```

And I tried to apply the so-called batching transformation to it as follows:

```
def withBatching[F[_]](t: Test[F], nat: F ~> F[List[*]]): Test[F[List[*]]] = ???
```

The problem is it does not compile with the following error:

```
[error] /Hello.scala:15:66: F[[α$1$]List[α$1$]] takes no type parameters, expected: 1
[error]   def withBatching[F[_]](t: Test[F], nat: F ~> F[List[*]]): Test[F[List[*]]] = ???
[error]                                                                  ^
[error] /Hello.scala:15:48: F[[α$0$]List[α$0$]] takes no type parameters, expected: 1
[error]   def withBatching[F[_]](t: Test[F], nat: F ~> F[List[*]]): Test[F[List[*]]] = ???
```

Is there a way to declare somethign like `F[List[*]]` with kind projector?

**UPD**: I found some workaround with type aliasing `type ListT[F[_], A] = F[List[A]]` which seems to work, but is there more natural way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` always binds at the tightest level, which is not what you need for `nat` and the return type. You should use `Lambda` syntax provided by kind-projector to explicitly choose the level:

```scala
  def withBatching[F[_]](
      t: Test[F], nat: F ~> Lambda[A => F[List[A]]]
  ): Test[Lambda[A => F[List[A]]]] = ???
```